# How to find the time complexity of an algorithm based on a number of steps

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity, big-o

What is the "Big O" time complexity for a program wherein the relation between the input size `n` and a number of steps is:

```
input size | steps
-------------------
  4        |    29
  6        |   175
  8        |   649
 10        |  1835
 12        |  4334
 14        |  9063
 16        | 16976
 18        | 29842
```

It seems to start at less than `n**3` and then grows to require less than `n**4` and doesn't seem to be exponential, isn't it?

Comment: No algorithm given? I think you'll just have to find a function that fits the curve with R^2 as close to 1 as possible. For a single term, `O(x**4.5797)` seems to fit pretty well, but I'm not sure if that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Anything is helpful. Thank-you.  I'm still new to Big O.  The system seems to get "Relatively" better with input size.  I haven't coded it out just yet.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** this is *impossible* to know precisely since there is an *infinite* amount of plausible solutions.

---

You can use a polynomial regression to *guess* the degree of the complexity *assuming it is polynomial* and the behaviour of the algorithm is *uniform* (ie. the algorithm does not contain any conditional structure impacting the number of steps).

Here are the raw results (the R2 is a metric describing the quality of the regression -- where R2=1 means it is close to perfect):

```
If the degree is 1:
    Function = y(x) = 1,748.905x^1 + -11,850.452
    R2 = 0.81
    Mean Squared Errors: 15062257.81
    Root Mean Squared Errors: 3881.012

If the degree is 2:
    Function = y(x) = 207.807x^2 + -2,822.839x^1 + 8,930.202
    R2 = 0.993
    Mean Squared Errors: 552581.235
    Root Mean Squared Errors: 743.358

If the degree is 3:
    Function = y(x) = 9.997x^3 + -122.089x^2 + 436.132x^1 + -306.881
    R2 = 0.999
    Mean Squared Errors: 77681.188
    Root Mean Squared Errors: 278.713

If the degree is 4:
    Function = y(x) = -0.835x^4 + 46.721x^3 + -685.349x^2 + 3,940.647x^1 + -7,609.702
    R2 = 1
    Mean Squared Errors: 37326.804
    Root Mean Squared Errors: 193.201

If the degree is 5:
    Function = y(x) = -0.239x^5 + 12.293x^4 + -226.968x^3 + 1,992.662x^2 + -8,223.310x^1 + 12,674.167
    R2 = 1
    Mean Squared Errors: 4825.15
    Root Mean Squared Errors: 69.463
```

Based on this, you can safely say that the complexity is not linear and not quadratic. For other degrees, it is not possible to say which one is the "correct" one. The reason for that is 1. there is **not enough measures** to discriminate the possible solutions, and 2. **any mathematical function can be approximated using an arbitrary high-degree polynomial function** (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory) for more information approximation theory).

If you want to be sure about the complexity of an algorithm **you need analyze the code** and not its black-box behaviour.

Comment: For completeness, it is also definitely not exponential, which gives R^2 of 0.9614 for `9.5395 e^(0.4774 * x)`

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  So you would say that it is a polynomial run time algorithm of some kind, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the complement Calculuswhiz. @ArchieGillis yes, *probably* (without the algorithm pseudo-code, or at least more information, we cannot be sure).